# Installation of wkhtmltopdf fails in docker environment

Tags: docker, dockerfile, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to install wkhtmltopdf in my docker environment. what ever I try it fails. my current Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM python:3.8.5

...
...

# Installation of dependencies Abhängigkeiten
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y ghostscript -f
RUN apt-get install -y fontforge -f
RUN apt-get install -y cabextract -f
RUN wget https://gist.github.com/maxwelleite/10774746/raw/ttf-vista-fonts-installer.sh -q -O - | bash

RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -f
RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
```

and this ends with the following error codes

```
Step 13/32 : RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb
 ---> Running in 49712db15630
Selecting previously unselected package wkhtmltox.
(Reading database ... 26470 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking wkhtmltox (1:0.12.6-1.bionic) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wkhtmltox:
 wkhtmltox depends on libjpeg-turbo8; however:
  Package libjpeg-turbo8 is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-75dpi; however:
  Package xfonts-75dpi is not installed.
 wkhtmltox depends on xfonts-base; however:
  Package xfonts-base is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package wkhtmltox (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wkhtmltox
The command '/bin/sh -c dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.bionic_amd64.deb' returned a non-zero code: 1
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

i tried with all different available wkhtmltopdf installations and none of it worked. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use apt-get install to fix up missing dependencies. Example:

```
FROM python:3.8.5
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
 apt-utils ghostscript fontforge cabextract \
 wget
ARG WKHTML2PDF_VERSION='0.12.6-1'
RUN export VERSION_CODENAME=$(. /etc/os-release; echo $VERSION_CODENAME) \
 && wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/${WKHTML2PDF_VERSION}/wkhtmltox_${WKHTML2PDF_VERSION}.${VERSION_CODENAME}_amd64.deb -O wkhtmltox.deb
RUN dpkg -i wkhtmltox.deb || apt-get install -f -y
```

Comment: the problem with getting wkhtmltopdf from apt is, that some needed features like adding header and footers are missing. thats why i try to get the complete package

Comment: Okay, is the issue that you need a more recent version? If so, do you know what the minimum version you need is?

Comment: no I'm not sure what min-Version i would need, but i have nothing fancy in mind. header/footer and some pictures is the most.
On the pip-docs of pdfkit it says the following:
"Warning! Version in debian/ubuntu repos have reduced functionality (because it compiled without the wkhtmltopdf QT patches), such as adding outlines, headers, footers, TOC etc. To use this options you should install static binary from wkhtmltopdf site or you can use this script."

Comment: @user2828408 I see - Look at the edit and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems here. First, you are trying to install an Ubuntu Bionic Beaver version of WKHTMLTOPDF on a Debian Buster os. So, I would recommend using the correct release.

Second, you are clearly missing some dependencies as stated in the error message. So you should install those.

Lastly, this is purely optional, but I would recommend grouping your install commands in one layer (one Docker command here `RUN`), this will help make your final image smaller.

Here is the content of a Dockerfile that would build.

```
FROM python:3.8.5

RUN set -e; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        apt-utils \
        ghostscript \
        fontforge \
        cabextract \
        wget \
        libjpeg62-turbo \
        xfonts-75dpi \
        xfonts-base; \
    wget https://gist.github.com/maxwelleite/10774746/raw/ttf-vista-fonts-installer.sh -q -O - | bash; \
    wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb ; \
    dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.buster_amd64.deb; \
    rm -rf rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Cheers

Comment: Oh yes, the wrong architecture-build got stuck from the last try (was so desperate to try even other builds ). The following error comes up now again: `Package 'libjpeg-turbo8' has no installation candidate`

Comment: My bad, that was trying with two Dockerfiles, the jpeg library is `libjpeq62-turbo` on buster